# What is going on in the solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

With
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b  \\
    c & d  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
B = \begin{bmatrix}
    p & q  \\
    r & s  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

find the matrix of the linear transformation $T(x)=B(Ax)$.

The answer:

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=B\left(A\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right)=B\begin{bmatrix}a\\c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}pa+qc\\ra+sc\end{bmatrix}\\T\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=B\left(A\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)=B\begin{bmatrix}b\\d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}pb+qd\\rb+sd\end{bmatrix}\\\text{So, }T\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}=x_1\left(T\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right)+x_2\left(T\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}b\\d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}pb+qd\\rb+sd\end{bmatrix}$$

However, I have no clue what is going on in the solution guide.
They have a $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ matrix and then a $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ matrix. How did they get those?

Comment: What do you mean by a 1,0 matrix and a 0,1 matrix?

Comment: the T 1 0 matrix and then the T 0 1 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant $$\begin{pmatrix}pa+qc & pb+qd\\
ra+sc & rb+sd\end{pmatrix}$$

That is the matrix obtained by putting $T\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $T\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ together as two columns. This is the typical way to find the matrix of a transformation.

In this case, it can also be obtained by multiplying $BA$.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the value on elements of basis of the (finite dimensional) vector space is enough to find the value on any point in the vector space. In this case, the transformations are acting on $\mathbb{R}^2$, which has $\{ (1, 0), (0, 1) \}$ as one of the basis. You don't need to take this basis, but it is easier, as 
$$ a= (a_1 , a_2) = a_1 (1,0) + a_2(0,1)$$
In case of any other basis, you'll have to explicitly calculate the coefficients.
You can read up Hoffman and Kunze, Linear Algebra (chapter on Vector spaces) for further clarification.